# fill pattern postion not same with pattern position

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns

[image]

I created a pattern which is 4in x 1in.
I added it as a pattern.

[image]

In another layer, I draw a big rectangle and fill with the pattern.

[image]

Unfortunately, the fill in pattern was not the same position with pattern.
How to prevent the position running out.

Updated process of filling pattern issue
[image]

Comment: Can you explain *why* you need the pattern to align with identical, non-pattern, objects? Or is it just that you want the patterns to start at the top left corner of your artboard? Pattern Swatches offset their contents by nature to prevent the repetition being more noticeable and makes seams less prominent. You *can* adjust the pattern tile.

Comment: @scott I want it to start end the top. I want the fill in pattern position exactly with the pattern position.

Comment: Did you read the answers? They provide methods of moving the pattern. Pattern fills simply never start at 0,0 in Illustrator. It's just not the way Illustrator works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Select the pattern filled rectangle
- Choose `Object > Transform > Move`
- **Untick** `Transform Objects`
- **Tick** `Transform Patterns`
- Change the `Horizontal` and `Vertical` fields to move the pattern to where you want it.

[image]

<sub>(This, combined with @BillyKerr's answer, should get you what you want.)</sub>

Admittedly, I don't see why you need a pattern offhand. There may be some reason I'm unaware of. If you simply want to repeat those 4 squares down the artboard, you don't need a pattern. Just repeat them. A pattern may be unwarranted overhead. If you want to use a pattern, you don't need the *4* duplicates to create the tile, you merely need 1.

Patterns *intentionally* auto-offset to create a more seamless appearance overall.

---

It's also possible move, scale, rotate, etc. *just the pattern fill* of a shape, *without* altering the shape itself, by holding down the Grave <kbd>`</kbd> key (which is also Tilde <kbd>~</kbd> with shift - if your keyboard has that key - immediately left of the <kbd>1</kbd> key) while you click-drag with the cursor.

Comment: In Windows 11, with my UK keyboard, the shortcut for clicking and dragging the pattern is the grave accent key which is to the immediate left of the 1 key.

Comment: And, to confuse matters further, in Windows, the Tilde is the shortcut for the Curvature Tool.   As for other keyboard locales, I have heard some have difficulty accessing the grave accent key.

Comment: Yes, same key -- it is the Grave and Tilde key here.. I've just always called it the Tilde key and seen it referenced that way.. even though Tilde is *technically* shift-grave.

Comment: It's different on Windows though, and it may also differ by keyboard locale. The tilde is on another key on a UK keyboard, and is located on a different key from the grave accent.

Comment: Oh `:)` same key here.. Grave, then shift-Grave for Tilde. - I know it varies, which is why I added the parenthesis there `:)` Some keyboards don't have a Tilde at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible method.

Draw a shape, apply the pattern fill.

Do *Object > Transform > Move*.  Set it to 0mm (horizontal) and 0mm (vertical), enable the *Transform Objects* option, but make sure you **deselect the *Transform Patterns* option**, and hit OK.

[image]

Now when you draw additional shapes, the patterns will align. Even if you move them, the patterns will still align.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply. Please check this https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkcBx.gif
I have use transform but still unable to fill the pattern start from the beginning.

Comment: @e12345678 Then just move the pattern as per Scott's answer.